# Upload files to Google Drive from a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I'm not a savvy coder, so this is quite a challenge to me, but I'm trying to get this to work anyway:

I'm preparing a registration form on Google Forms. People will insert their personal data and, in the end, I would need people to be able to upload a few files (a photo, a CV, etc...). Such files would be stored on Google Drive.

Now, I've seen that there seems to be no straightforward way of doing it on Google Forms. I was thinking that my only option would be to try and get it done with Google Scripts and then embed that script inside my Google Form.

Is this possible? Can anyone help me with this?

Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: **Amit Agarwal** has a nice post on how to [Upload Files to Google Drive with Google Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files). You won't be able to embed the script in Google Forms, but you can retrieve all the information via the HTML form.

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion. I had already seen that, but not being able to make it work the way I need to - mainly due to my own low knowledge base...

Comment: What have you actually tried? Show us what you've done.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a Google bussines account, you can create a file upload question type. See the announce here https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/10/five-new-ways-to-reach-your-goals.html